# Rust lifetimes - returning value from vector in RWLock in Arc

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having a lot of trouble with lifetimes in relation to Arcs and RWLocks.

```rust
struct ComponentContainer<T>{
    id_to_component: HashMap<uint, uint>,
    components: Arc<RWLock<~Vec<T>>>
}
```

id_to_component is a map of component ids to an index into the Vec inside components.

I've tried everything from the intuitive:

```rust
impl<T: Component> ComponentContainer<T>{
    fn get<'a>(&'a self, id: uint) -> &'a T {
        let idx = self.id_to_component.get(&id);
        self.components.read().get(*idx)
    }
}
```

To the extremely verbose (manually storing each reference):

```rust
impl<T: Component> ComponentContainer<T> {
    fn get<'a>(&'a self, id: uint) -> &'a T {
        let idx = self.id_to_component.get(&id);
        let components: &'a RWLock<~Vec<T>> = &'a *self.components;
        let c: &'a RWLock<~Vec<T>> = &'a *components;
        let tmp: &'a RWLockReadGuard<'a, ~Vec<T>> = &'a c.read();
        let v: &'a ~Vec<T> = &'a **tmp;
        v.get(*idx)
    }
}
```

With the verbose one, I end up getting the error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
let tmp: &'a RWLockReadGuard<'a, ~Vec<T>> = &'a c.read();
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

According to the source for RWLock.read(), the returned reference should have the specified lifetime, unless I'm reading it incorrectly.

Edit: full rustc output for short version

```
test.rs:18:9: 18:31 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
test.rs:18         self.components.read().get(*idx)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:16:45: 19:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime &'a  as defined on the block at 16:44...
test.rs:16     fn get<'a>(&'a self, id: uint) -> &'a T {
test.rs:17         let idx = self.id_to_component.get(&id);
test.rs:18         self.components.read().get(*idx)
test.rs:19     }
test.rs:16:45: 19:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 16:44
test.rs:16     fn get<'a>(&'a self, id: uint) -> &'a T {
test.rs:17         let idx = self.id_to_component.get(&id);
test.rs:18         self.components.read().get(*idx)
test.rs:19     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated, but why `~Vec<T>`? From my limited knowledge, `Vec<T>` should work fine.

Comment: At that point, I was just trying anything, tbh. Forgot it was there

Comment: with c.read() you are just taking a reference to a value and throwing the value away, that's what colpiler is telling you

Comment: afaik, .read() is the way to access a value within a RWLock. How would I need to change it to not throw the value away?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the [signature of `read()`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/sync/raw/struct.RWLock.html#method.read):

```rust
fn read<'a>(&'a self) -> RWLockReadGuard<'a>
```

It returns a `RWLockReadGuard<'a>`. That's not a reference to a `RWLockReadGuard`, it's a `RWLockReadGuard`, *containing inside it* references of lifetime `'a`.

Now your line:

```rust
let tmp: &'a RWLockReadGuard<'a, ~Vec<T>> = &'a c.read();
```

You are taking a reference to the `RWLockReadGuard`. That means that the referenced object must live for at least as long as the reference. But this is not the case: the value is the value returned by `c.read()`, *which is not stored anywhere*. Because it is not stored anywhere, it is discarded at the end of the statement, and so the borrow is invalid, because the required `'a` is longer than the statement and so cannot be satisfied.

What you should do instead is simply drop the `&'a` part, using the object directly:

```rust
let tmp: RWLockReadGuard<'a, ~Vec<T>> = c.read();
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with your short version at first glance, and I don't have rustc handy. Please post the full rustc stderr.

Comment: It looks like my main issue is that the RWLockReadGuard doesn't have the 'a lifetime, and so when I try to return a value from inside it, rustc is complaining about the lock going out of scope before the data.  So I guess the main question at this point would be how to get a RWLockReadGuard to have the appropriate lifetime.